# If garage door circuit board is fried by power surge, wouldn't outlet also be fried?

Tags: electrical, garage

The control/circuit board is dead in Wayne Dalton opener. Is covered by our American Home Shield warranty. However, because tech suggested to AHS work "approval dept" that it could have been fried by a power surge, they are denying the claim. Tech said to me that he doesn't know for a fact that this happened because of a power surge but was merely hypothesizing because he was pressed for a reason the board went bad. At any rate, I am wondering if a power surge DID cause this, wouldn't the receptacle show signs of damage? Wouldn't the other thing (a shop light) also be damaged?  Would it have tripped a breaker? Just looking for ammo to AHS to cover my claim. They tend find a way to deny everything. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 7):

Anything with sensitive electronics is more susceptible to damage due to power surges. Receptacles don't have any electronics (unless they're GFCI or AFCI receptacles), and it's doubtful that a shop light has any either.  If a surge is not large enough to trip the magnetic protection, or long enough to trip the thermal protection, then the breaker will not trip.

It sounds to me like they have no idea what caused the failure, and are simply guessing.

Comment: That is what figured but wasn't sure. Appreciate the clarification and your speedy reply!

Answer (score 0):

Schemes like this are just a ripoff. Do you really think an insurance company is going to be able fix stuff in your home? You are just "talking to the hand". If the $100 or whatever it is for a new controller is that important to you, I would recommend calling Wayne Dalton's customer service at (800) 827-3667 and asking for a replacement. I will bet you anything they will send you a new controller if you send them the old one.

Comment: I've had a "home warranty" for many years...different companies in different homes. HAVE had them work out (one replaced an HVAC system at a cost to me of $75; ditto dead garage disposals, etc). HOWEVER, that was in the past and I am going to cancel this policy pronto. Never occurred to me to contact Wayne Dalton (but yes, every penny matters to me) since the opener is over 5 years old but I did order a new circuit board from another garage door parts place and am going to replace it myself for a total of $60 (which is less than the AHS service call was and which the Overhead Door guys waved).